# Request with NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I tried to make an login page to make user authenticate to the website. I tried something like:

```
    NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.freelancer.com/users/onlogin.php"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                            timeoutInterval:60];    
NSLog(@"ispost");
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:usernameField.text forKey:@"username"];
[request setValue:passwordField.text forKey:@"passwd"];


NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (!theConnection) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Network Error" message:@"Could not login!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    return;
}
```

I got an erroras followed:

`2012-07-07 10:09:37.354 Auth[6062:f803] ispost
2012-07-07 10:09:37.357 Auth[6062:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<NSMutableURLRequest 0x68d69d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.'`

Can anyone suggest me what i did wrong?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use like

```
[request setValue:usernameField.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"username"];
[request setValue:passwordField.text forHTTPHeaderField:@"passwd"];
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

NSMutableURLRequest doesn't have a username property (hence the error). You need to do something like the following (though it depends on what format your server is expecting):

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"username=%@&passwd=%@", usernameField.text, passwordField.text];
[request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, it works fine but it doesn't work through the `didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge` how can i work with it to check the authentication user

Comment: Yes, i implemented the method already but it seem like `didReceiveAuthenticationChalleng` is not be called.

Comment: I got it work through the `didReceiveAuthenticationChalleng` but it doesn't go to an `else` even if i put the wrong username or password. Can you advice me?

Comment: In order to track that down, I'll have to see the code. I'd suggest closing this question and starting a new one with a link back.

Comment: Here is a link of my question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11380843/1449381)

Answer (score 0):

The hint is in your error string:

> this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.

I'm pretty sure you can't do basic auth in the way you are attempting. A quick search turned up [this](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/basic_authentication_iphone_cocoa_touch), and I do recall having to do base64 when trying to pass it with every request (the alternative is implementing the connection delegate methods, and properly handling the request for auth.